# Python: Running Code using Jupyter Notebook (Online)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, module, jupyter-notebook

I am new to the world of Python. I am using a computer with very little space left, so I decided to try to use the online version of Python without explicitly installing anacondas or python.

I used this link over here: https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/ipython-ipython-in-depth-eer5tgdf/notebooks/binder/Index.ipynb# , and then I opened a new file. I am trying to re-run the code from this github repository : https://github.com/brohrer/byo_decision_tree/blob/main/decision_tree.py

I tried running the following code and got this error:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from tree_node import TreeNode

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
​
from tree_node import TreeNode
​
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-984dee29eb66> in <module>
      2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 
----> 4 from tree_node import TreeNode

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tree_node'
```

This line is preventing me from running the rest of the code. Can someone please show me what am I doing wrong?

1. Is it simply not possible to run python code online without having downloaded anaconda?
2. Or am I approaching this problem the wrong way? Perhaps the version of python I am using is incorrect? Or there are some dependencies required that I have not yet installed.

Can someone please show me how to resolve this problem?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You need to install the library tree_node... I'm not sure if this is possible through the online version of Jupyter notebook. I recommend using anaconda so you're environment isn't dependent on online sources though.

Answer (score 1):

To simplify the development different functionalities are allocated to different scripts/modules.

You are simply taking the main script (`decision_tree.py`) and trying to run it. But it has some imports from other modules. For example, in the directory where you opened `decision_tree.py`, there is also `tree_node.py`, which has `TreeNode` class, which is imported into `decision_tree.py`.

So, one of the options is to copy this `TreeNode` class into `decision_tree.py` and put it above `DecisionTree` class.

Comment: Here are some updates. I downloaded the corresponding zip file. Then, I unzipped it, and uploaded it into the online python console. Now, I am waiting for it to run (it's taking a really long time): https://imgur.com/a/SKKpG75

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Colab. It is free and you can access it from your google drive account. Basically Colab is a Jupiter notebook running on cloud. If you are familiar with Jupiter notebook, you will learn Colab quickly.

For more Information : [Google Colab](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

Comment: I just opened it right now: https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb#scrollTo=GJBs_flRovLc  I assume I should just be able to enter python code here?

Comment: Yes you are. Also, check tis pages: 
 [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/github/cs231n/cs231n.github.io/blob/master/python-colab.ipynb)
and
[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inN8seMm7UI)

Comment: Can you please show me how to "import" the zip file (byo_decision_tree.zip) into google colab? https://imgur.com/a/4TOwz1N

Comment: You can upload the file on your drive  and import from there. Check the link for more information:  [similar question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/29480/uploading-images-folder-from-my-system-into-google-colab)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to !pip install tree_node  ? No module usually means module not installed.

Comment: Yes, I am waiting for it to run: https://imgur.com/a/SKKpG75